# How to prevent BBC UK from auto-redirecting to the international site?

Tags: bbc

It looks like that non-UK visitors are being auto-redirected from `https://bbc.co.uk` to `http://bbc.com`. (Notice how the latter site isn’t HTTPS, which makes it doubly annoying.) I would like to browse their UK site.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: It won't let me answer the question, but yes this is possible with UBlock Origin. Create a rule to block `||static.files.bbci.co.uk/orbit/*/js/redirect.js`. That works for me, at least

Comment: Actually that's not enough for every page, but it works for some. `||www.bbc.co.uk/userinfo` too will fix it for others (but may break the login functionality, if you care about that.)

Answer (score 1):

No. A lot of material that is free in the UK once a licence fee has been paid is sold for audiences outside UK. To enter the UK site you might choose a suitable proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent the redirect, but you can still read the articles.
In the two seconds that you can view the .uk page before redirect occurs, try to right-click on the link to the story that you want to read.  That will open up a menu, that includes 'copy' and 'open new window'. The content of this menu is preserved, even while the website content changes from .uk .com.  So you can open the articles and read them.